# IBOutlet Label does not get data

Tags: ios, uilabel, ios6

Hi I am newbie in StackOverFlow and iOS 6..

It will be so simple for experienced developer..

in .h file..

```
@interface NotKnownDetailView : UITableViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *wordLabel;
@end
```

in .m file..

```
@interface NotKnownDetailView ()
    - (void)configureView;
@end

@implementation NotKnownDetailView
@synthesize  wordLabel = _wordLabel ;

- (void)configureView{

    wordData *theSighting = self.word_data;

    if (theSighting) {

        UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello World!"
                                                          message:theSighting.verbal
                                                         delegate:nil
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [message show];

        self.wordLabel.text = theSighting.word;

        UIAlertView *message2 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello World!"
                                                          message: self.verbalLabel.text
                                                         delegate:nil
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [message2 show];

    }
}
```

Problem is as follows..

```
self.wordLabel.text = theSighting.word;
```

In spite of theSighting.word has data, but self.wordLabel.text does not contain any data...

Absolutely I connected the IBOutlet in storyboard.

What is wrong above?.

**Edited.**
I add some part of source. I hope you are not uncomfortable with this.

```
//  NotKnownDetailView.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class wordData ;

@interface NotKnownDetailView : UITableViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) wordData *word_data;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *wordLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *meanLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *verbalLabel;
@end


//  NotKnownDetailView.m

#import "NotKnownDetailView.h"
#import "wordData.h"

@interface NotKnownDetailView ()
//@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPopoverController *masterPopoverController;
- (void)configureView;
@end

@implementation NotKnownDetailView
@synthesize word_data = _word_data, wordLabel = _wordLabel, meanLabel = _meanLabel, verbalLabel = _verbalLabel;

// it is getter setter.. 
- (void)setWord_data:(wordData *) newWord
{
    if (_word_data != newWord) {
        _word_data = newWord;
        [self configureView];
    }
}
- (void)configureView
{

    wordData *theSighting = self.word_data;

    if (theSighting) {
        NSLog(@" Word : %@" ,theSighting.word);

        self.wordLabel.text = theSighting.word;
        self.meanLabel.text = theSighting.mean;
        self.verbalLabel.text = theSighting.verbal;

    }
}
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    self.word_data = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

}

@end







//  wordData.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface wordData : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *word;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *mean;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *verbal;
-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)word meaning:(NSString *)mean verbaling:(NSString *)verbal;
@end


//  wordData.m

#import "wordData.h"

@implementation wordData
@synthesize word = _word, mean = _mean , verbal = _verbal ;

-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)word meaning:(NSString *)mean verbaling:(NSString *)verbal{
    {
        self = [super init];
        if (self) {
            _word= word;
            _mean = mean;
            _verbal = verbal ;
            return self;
        }
        return nil;
    }

}
@end
```

**SOLED.**

Comment: When is `-(void)configureView` called?

Comment: where do you call the method - (void)configureView ?

Comment: the configureView is called when class initiated.. as setter.

Comment: Well, then there you have it, on the init the `UIViews` have not being loaded yet... So they are `nil`.

Comment: Jacky Boy. You are right...

I add [self configureView];  in viewDidLoad..

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
       [super viewDidLoad];
       [self configureView]; 
    }
    

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are calling `-(void)configureView` before `-(void)viewDidLoad`, in which case `wordLabel` is `nil` when you are trying to assign anything to it.

Try calling `-(void)configureView` inside `-(void)viewDidLoad`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self configureView];
}
```

Comment: No problem. Did it fix your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm theSighting.word is an NSString value? Also I think if(theSighting) is used incorrectly. Make sure it's a bool value. Try using NSLog(@"%@" theSighting.word); to see if anything prints in debugger console.

Comment: Yes. It produces as follows..

2012-10-09 22:58:27.325 Headline[11893:c07]  Word : Pigeon

Comment: you might need to initialize your label in viewdidload, ex: self.wordLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];